# How do I resolve "react-snap error on running build"

Tags: reactjs, react-snap

I installed react snap to my react project and then when I run build it doesn't crawl each page instead shows some error. Previously it was working fine, but don't know what happened now. [this is the error which I am getting on running npm run build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcgJx.png)  It would be nice if I could get a quick solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add a preview of the error message you received instead of providing images references. Please also show the effort you made to solve this issue. Thanks!